# Why does Coldfusion 10 occupy 50% of available RAM instantly, without anything running?

Tags: memory, coldfusion, ram, coldfusion-10

We are running ColdFusion 10 in a Windows 2008 R2 Standard environment.

We notice that immediately upon launching ColdFusion services, it eats 4 - 5 gigs of available RAM (we have 8 gigs available).

This occurs even though nothing is actually happening. No pages are running, no processes are going, literally nothing is happening. It occupies this RAM immediately upon launch.

Was wondering if anyone has Experienced this before, and whether there is something in the default settings of ColdFusion admin that we may have screwed up?

Comment: Is it occupying it physically or only virtually? A lot of applications tend to allocate a lot of logical space but due to the way paging works this only means the OS creates mappings for them but doesn't assign them to physical pages so it's quite possible that it's just doing this pre allocation.

Comment: You can specify how much RAM CF10 uses: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7feb

Answer (score 10):

Check your JVM.config file. You will probably find settings like:

```
-Xmx4096
-Xms4096
```

The important one in this context is `Xms`. That is the minimum size of the heap space for the JVM. Which means that the JVM will immediately claim that much memory regardless of what it is doing. This is OK. This is how I handle my servers.

Having `Xmx` and `Xms` set to the same values is usually recommended because if you start with a smaller heap it takes time and resources for the heap to grow to the size that you need it. Performance is usually better if the JVM just claims all the memory it needs up front.